# Matlab read one digit at a time from text file

Tags: matlab

I have a file that contains byte values `0` or `1` that are formatted without any whitespace between, like `1010111101010010010101`. I want to make a `[1, 0, 1, ...]` vector out of those, reading one digit at a time. How can I do that? I tried using `fscanf(fileId,'%c')` but I get ASCII codes instead of actual values. `'%d'` on the other hand reads the entire file as one number.

I also tried writing to file:

```
fprintf(file1,'%d ',matrix); //notice the space after `%d`
```

and reading

```
fscanf(file2,'%d');
```

but I get a `Nx1` matrix and I want to keep it as `1xN`.

I could transpose it to be horizontal, but I still need to add space between digits, and I don't want to do that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert easily from ascii char code to integer format as follows:

```
   text = fscanf(fileId,'%c') - '0' ;
```

Note that you will also pick up end-of-line characters this way if there are any.

If you only have 0/1 in your file, using `fileread` will accomplish the same thing but also catches EOL characters:

```
 text = fileread('test.txt');
 text = text' - '0';
```

You can also read the entire file with `textread`:

```
text = textread('test.txt','%s');
text = char(text) - '0' ;
```

Now lines are returned in a cell array with one row per line. `char` then converts the cell array to a regular char array. This will not capture EOL characters but `char` will append blank spaces (ascii code 32) if the lines are not all equal in length.

Finally, you can also read line by line by looping and applying `fgetl` at each iteration until the function returns a -1.

```
  while ~isnumeric(c)
     c = fscanf(fileId,'%c') 
     c - '0';
  end
```

This avoids reading EOL characters and appending blank space but you need to handle catenating the data.